# kinect: nonsense point clouds for 30 seconds after subscribing

Tags: openni-kinect, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I launch the kinect driver and processing nodes with openni_launch/launch/openni.launch. I have the latest versions of the ROS-openni packages in Electric. I get xyzrgb point clouds, but the depth data is nonsense for 30 seconds after subscribing. Here's a video, where I'm viewing the point cloud in rviz on a remote computer: http://surgical1.cs.berkeley.edu/troubleshooting/rviz_kinect.ogv. This isn't a network issue--I have the exact same problem when I record data on the local computer that the kinect is connected to--c1 on the pr2.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11907/kinect:-nonsense-point-clouds-for-30-seconds-after-subscribing/) by [joschu](https://answers.ros.org/users/896/joschu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2011-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your link is broken.

Two things to try: plugging the Kinect into a different computer, and a different Kinect. Maybe you've got a bad part...

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I forgot to update this post until I noticed that there was a reply. As Mac correctly inferred, this was hardware problem with the kinect itself. Apparently the electronics or wiring was damaged when we prepared the kinect to be mounted.

---

Originally posted by [joschu](https://answers.ros.org/users/896/joschu/) with karma: 131 on 2012-05-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1